# Rotated shapes not appearing on an Applet

Tags: java, swing, applet

I'm making a Pinball style applet and I ran into some problems before that have thankfully been remedied. However, I've hit another stumbling block.

To draw flippers for the pinball machine, I intended to draw an angled rounded rectangle which would allow me to possibly animate it later on so that you could see it moving up when I add threads to the applet. This is all done in the Table's paintComponent method. When I don't apply any rotation to check that it's all working ok, it draws the shape fine. But when I apply a rotation (whether through an Affine Transform object as in my code now or the Graphics2D.rotate method) the shape does not draw for some reason. I'm not sure why but I'm hoping that I've merely overlooked something. I have looked around online, but either I'm not putting in the right keywords or it is simply that I'm overlooking something.

The code for my Pinball and Table classes is below, please feel free to point out anything that you think could cause this strangeness. Note that I haven't given the right coordinates exactly yet as I can tweek it's position when it's drawn and I can see it, in case any of you run any similar code to try and debug it.

As a P.S. Would calling the ball's constructor on table be a better idea than doing it on the applet? Just wondering if what I've done with that is really inefficient.

```
import javax.swing.*; // useful for the drawing side, also going to be a JApplet
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Pinball extends JApplet
{
    // variables go here
    Table table;
    Player player;
    Ball ball;
    Miosoft miosoft;
    Miofresh miofresh;
    Mioboost mioboost;
    Miocare miocare;
    Miowipe miowipe;

    // further initialisation of the GUI
    public void init()
    {
        setSize(300, 300);
        table = new Table(this);
        player = new Player();
        ball = new Ball(180, 175); // set the ball's initial position in the arguments
        miosoft = new Miosoft();
        miocare = new Miocare();
        miowipe = new Miowipe();
        miofresh = new Miofresh();
        mioboost = new Mioboost();
        setContentPane(table); // makes our graphical JPanel container the content pane for the Applet
        // createGUI(); // this has been moved onto the table class
    }

    public void stop()
    {
    }

// little getters to make things easier on the table
    public int getBallX()
    {
        return ball.getXPosition();
    }

    public int getBallY()
    {
        return ball.getYPosition();
    }

    public int getLives()
    {
        return player.getLives();
    }

    public int getScore()
    {
        return player.getScore();
    }
}
```

And here is the table class

```
import java.awt.*; // needed for old style graphics stuff
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*; // gives us swing stuff
import sun.rmi.transport.LiveRef;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*; // useful for anything using URLs
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------
Auto-generated Java code for class Table

Generated by QSEE-SuperLite multi-CASE, QSEE-Technologies Ltd
www.qsee-technologies.com
Further developed to be the Content pane of this application by Craig Brett
----------------------------------------------------------------*/

public class Table extends JPanel
{
    // attributes go here
    Pinball pb;
    Color bgColour;
    Color launcherColour;
    Color ballColour;
    Image logo;
    Image freshBonus;
    Image midCircle;
    Image leftBumper;
    Image rightBumper;
    Image nappy1;
    Image nappy2;
    Image nappy3;
    int ballX;
    int ballY;
    int playerLives;
    int playerScore;

    // constructor goes here
    public Table(Pinball pb)
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        this.pb = pb;
        // this is not needed anymore, with the new loadImage class down the bottom
        //  Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); // needed to get images
        //  logo = tk.getImage(base + "images/bambinomio.jpg");
        logo = loadImage("bambinomio.jpg");
        freshBonus = loadImage("miofresh circle.jpg");
        midCircle = loadImage("middle circle.jpg");
        leftBumper = loadImage("left bumper.jpg");
        rightBumper = loadImage("right bumper.jpg");
        nappy1 = loadImage("nappy1.jpg");
        nappy2 = loadImage("nappy2.jpg");
        nappy3 = loadImage("nappy3.jpg");
        createGUI();
    }

    // public methods go here
    // all GUI creation stuff goes here
    public void createGUI()
    {
        // setting the background colour
        bgColour = new Color(190, 186, 221); // makes the sky blue colour for the background.
        setBackground(bgColour);
        launcherColour = new Color(130, 128, 193);
        ballColour = new Color(220, 220, 220); // the color of the launch spring and ball
        // setOpaque(false);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // to give us access to the 2D graphics features
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        // creating the panels
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(200, 20, 100, 280); // the logo Panel
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 20);
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawRoundRect(230, 125, 40, 120, 20, 20); // the lives panel
        g2d.drawRoundRect(210, 255, 80, 40, 20, 20);
        g2d.drawString("Score", 215, 270);
        g2d.drawString(displayScore(), 215, 290);
        // now drawing the graphics
        g2d.drawImage(logo, 205, 25, 90, 90, null);
        g2d.drawImage(freshBonus, 10, 40, 20, 20, this);
        g2d.drawImage(leftBumper, 40, 200, 10, 20, this);
        g2d.drawImage(rightBumper, 150, 200, 10, 20, this);
        // now the three mid circles
        g2d.drawImage(midCircle, 55, 120, 25, 25, this);
        g2d.drawImage(midCircle, 95, 90, 25, 25, this);
        g2d.drawImage(midCircle, 95, 150, 25, 25, this);
        // now filling out the lives depending on how many the players have
        playerLives = pb.getLives();
        if(playerLives >= 1)
            g2d.drawImage(nappy1, 235, 135, 32, 30, this);
        if(playerLives >= 2)
            g2d.drawImage(nappy2, 235, 170, 32, 30, this);
        if(playerLives >= 3)
            g2d.drawImage(nappy3, 235, 205, 32, 30, this);
        // now to handle the white lines
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.drawLine(20, 250, 20, 60); // the left edge
        g2d.drawArc(10, 40, 20, 20, 45, 225); // the top left corner
        g2d.drawLine(28, 43, 160, 43); // the top of the table
        g2d.drawArc(150, 41, 40, 30, 0, 120); // the top right corner
        g2d.drawLine(20, 250, 35, 270); // the bottom left corner
        // now for the launcher, we draw here
        g2d.setColor(launcherColour);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(170, 75, 30, 175, 20, 20); // the blue tube
        g2d.setColor(ballColour);
        g2d.fillRoundRect(175, 210, 20, 40, 20, 20); // the first bit of the launcher
        g2d.fillRect(175, 210, 20, 20); // the top of the launcher's firer
        g2d.fillRoundRect(175, 195, 20, 10, 20, 20); // the bit that hits the ball
        // now drawing the ball wherever it is
        ballX = pb.getBallX();
        ballY = pb.getBallY();
        g2d.fillOval(ballX, ballY, 10, 10);
        // now the flippers
        g2d.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        // more precise coordinates can be given when the transformation below works
        // RoundRectangle2D leftFlipper = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(43.0, 245.0, 20.0, 50.0, 30.0, 30.0); // have to make this using shape parameters
        // now using Affine Transformation to rotate the rectangles for the flippers
        AffineTransform originalTransform = g2d.getTransform();
        AffineTransform transform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(120));
        g2d.transform(transform); // apply the transform
        g2d.fillRoundRect(33, 260, 20, 40, 10, 10);
        g2d.setTransform(originalTransform); // resetting the angle
        // g2d.drawString("The flipper should be drawn", 80, 130); // for debugging if the previous draw instructions have been carried out
    }

    // a little useful method for handling loading of images and stuff
    public BufferedImage loadImage(String filename)
    {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(pb.getCodeBase(), "images/" + filename);
            image = ImageIO.read(url);
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error loading image - " + filename + ".");
        }
        return image;
    }

    private String displayScore()
    {
        playerScore = pb.getScore();
        String scoreString = Integer.toString(playerScore);
        String returnString = "";
        if(scoreString.length() < 8)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < (8 - scoreString.length()); i++)
            {
                returnString = returnString + "0";
            }
        }
        returnString = returnString + scoreString;
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Recommendations 1) Post one [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) rather than two source files comprising almost 200 lines of uncompilable code. 2) Use consistent & logical indentation & bracketing for code to make it clear where code blocks start & end. 3) Since this sounds like a problem that would show in a `JFrame`, use the frame instead.  Most people can run apps. more easily than applets. 4) Factor out the images, since this seems to be about shapes.

Comment: 1. What's uncompilable about my code?

Comment: Disregard the previous undeletable comment. Ok, I'll rewrite the code for that specification later. But 3 and 4 are undoable, since 3 is as good as a client constraint since the client wants something on their website that doesn't require a download and I don't believe an App would fit that. And it's an advergame, so images are important for it all. Thanks all the same, though.

Comment: I've formatted the code for you (thanks to NetBeans). Now would be nice if you can make a single code piece that is easily copyable and runnable. Good luck

Comment: @Craig:  "But 3 and 4 are undoable"  That's a pity, good luck with it.  And by that I mean that if you are not prepared to create code to debug the problem, that is specific to the problem, your chances of getting more specific help (than MBFG has already offered) are very small.  Note that point 3 can be accounted for by creating an hybrid application/applet.  Point 4 can use images that are generated in code (I would normally suggest hot-linking to images on the net, but that is not practical with the applet security sand-box - another reason I recommend the frames based demo.).

Comment: @Andrew, I think I was misunderstanding you, you were talking about those things to help with showing the problem as opposed to fixing it, I understand now, even though they wouldn't have been practical for the solution they might've helped in explaining the issue, I'll keep them in mind for next time. As it is, the answer below solved it, well @Trashgod's amendment helped a lot too. I never thought of trying that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally to rotate something, you rotate it around some point of interest (the anchor point of the thing that is rotating), not the point 0,0. It appears you are rotating around 0, 0 so chances are this is getting rotated off the screen. To rotate around an arbitrary point, first translate that point to 0 (negative translation) then rotate, then do translate back (postive translation).

Comment: +1 There's a [getRotateInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#getRotateInstance%28double,%20double,%20double%29) that includes the anchor, too.